# How to solve $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} ke^{-k}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, geometric-series

I am interested in

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} ke^{-k}$$

And I can get the closed form on Wolfram Alpha, $\frac{e}{(e-1)^2}$, but I am curious how to derive it. It doesn't appear to be a typical geometric series.

Comment: Solve $\sum e^{-k}$ and then take derivatives.

Comment: Here is one method you can try. First compute $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$ (geometrical series) and then show that $x f'(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k x^k$ and finally you just plug in $x= e^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to evaluate
$S 
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kx^k
$.

This is possibly the simplest.

$xS 
= x\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kx^k
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kx^{k+1}
= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (k-1)x^{k}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
S-xS
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kx^k-\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (k-1)x^{k}\\
&= x+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} kx^k-\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (k-1)x^{k}\\
&= x+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (kx^k-(k-1)x^{k})\\
&= x+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} x^k\\
&= x+\dfrac{x^2}{1-x}\\
&= \dfrac{x-x^2+x^2}{1-x}\\
&= \dfrac{x}{1-x}\\
\text{so}\\
S
&= \dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}\\
\end{array}
$

Then put $x = e^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

In fact it is the derivative of a geometric series because
$$
\left(e^{-kx}\right)'=-ke^{-kx}
$$
You can for example calculate for $x \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}e^{-kx}=\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}
$$
Then differenciating
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}ke^{-kx}=-\left(\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}\right)'=\frac{e^x}{\left(e^x-1\right)^2}
$$
Taking $x=1$ gives you the expected result.

Comment: It is true for any real $x$.

Comment: yes if $x>0$ to assure the sum exists

Answer (score 1):

For each real $x $, $e^{-x}<1$ and

$$e^{-x}+e^{-2x}+....=\frac {1}{1-e^{-x}} $$

differentiation gives

$$-(e^{-x}+2e^{-2x}+....)=\frac {-e^{-x}}{(1-e^{-x})^2} $$
$$=\frac {-e^x}{(e^x-1)^2} $$

For $x=1$, you get the result.

Answer (score 0):

**By elementary means:**

$$S:=a+a^2+a^2+a^3+a^3+a^3+a^4+a^4+a^4+a^4+\cdots\\
=(a+a^2+a^3+a^4+\cdots)+a(a+a^2+a^2+a^3+a^3+a^3+\cdots),$$

hence for $|a|<1$,

$$S=\frac a{1-a}+aS.$$

Comment: Crossed with @marty.